# Few questions about CORS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

So I wish to make some cross domain AJAX requests and wanted to check a few things.

- Is it possible to get CORS to work on IE < 8?
- I am required to ensure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set on the response from the server I am making an AJAX request to. Other than allowing every site to make a request, are there any security risks from setting this to `*`?
- From a client security perspective, **by DEFAULT** a CORS request does not sent cookies (e.g. session data) to the server I am making the AJAX request to. HOWEVER, it is possible to send cookie data etc...is this statement correct?

Comment: There has been a vote to close without a comment - care to expand?

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to **isolate an issue** that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get CORS to work on IE < 8?

Unfortunately not. Microsoft's XDomainRequest didn't arrive until IE8.

> Other than allowing every site to make a request, are there any security risks from setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *?

Strictly speaking no, but this in itself presents a range of potential security issues. Unless you need all origins allowed, configuring a whitelist is preferred.

> From a client security perspective, by DEFAULT a CORS request does not send cookies to the server I am making the AJAX request to. HOWEVER, it is possible. Is this statement correct?

Yes, correct. If you want to include cookies, you must configure the XHR's `withCredentials` property.

Additional information:

- [MDN Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)